# Unable to register aspnet_regiis.exe on my pc

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am running **aspnet_regiis.exe** file from command prompt but it is giving the following error.

[image]

Need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=216771?  It gives step by step instructions on how to install hook up .NET framework in IIS.